# The target table user of the INSERT is not insertable-into MariaDB 10.4.11

Tags: mariadb

I did a wonderful thing of deleting all root users from mysql by accident.  That kind of a day.

However before I panic I figured I would use this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085455/restoring-deleted-root-user-and-password-for-mysql) from searching online that  didn't seem so bad.

"*Add 'skip-grant-tables' to my.cnf under the [mysqld] section
restart mysql*"

then insert a new root user using "INSERT INTO mysql.user..."

When I do this I get an error I cannot find much information about

```
The target table user of the INSERT is not insertable-into
```

Does anyone have any ideas about this and how can I re-create a root user?

at first I thought this might have something to do with virtualmin because they talk about it [here](https://virtualmin.com/node/66724) but I did this from CLI into mysql and it still says the same error

my environment
Centos7

```
Webmin version 1.940
Usermin version|1.780
Virtualmin version 6.08
mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.11-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Comment: On related user authorization changes in MariaDB 10.4, see my answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/276298/216424

Answer (score 2):

I finally found my solution (big thanks to @RolandoMySQLDBA on this thread [here](https://superuser.com/questions/461043/how-to-access-mysql-when-i-delete-the-root-user-on-opensuse-11)).

The only problem I had with his answer was that `WITH GRANT OPTION;` was missing from `/var/lib/mysql/InitFile.sql`:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@localhost
IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Do not forget to remove the file when you are done and update to remove the init-file string you added to `/etc/my.cnf`.

I am still unsure why MariaDB was outputting error `INSERT is not insertable-into` and could not find any documentation explaining this was a MariaDB problem.

Comment: Thx! This worked. I edited @RolandoMySQLDBA answer.